# Porque realizar offloading para a GPU é uma boa idéia?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, vídeo, gpgpu

Eu acompanho alguns fóruns pela internet e percebo que recentemente se tem falado muito de realizar ***offloading*** das tarefas para a GPU.

A mozilla tem implementado um novo motor para seu navegador chamado `Servo`. Em seu coração ele faz o ***offloading*** de tudo que é possível para a GPU.

Até onde eu consigo entender, a GPU nada mais é que um processador adicional dedicado a renderização gráfica.

- Como a GPU pode auxiliar nos processamentos?
- Este ***offloading*** normalmente ocorre através de bibliotecas como a openMP. Em que exatamente estas bibliotecas auxiliam?
- Existe algum `overhead` de transferir estes processamentos para a GPU? Compensa pagar este `overhead` para processar na GPU?

Comment: Curiosamente o Servo é escrito em Rust :)

Comment: Sim, estou ciente que é escrito em Rust. Um dos pontos de critica a mozilla é por isso: eles falam que o servo é rápido por causa do Rust quando na verdade é por causa do offloading

Comment: Certamente tem esses marketings mesmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicamente: Quanto mais poder de processamento, melhor. Simples assim. Você não *deixa de usar* o CPU pra usar a GPU, mas utiliza ambos. Uma série de fenômenos históricos e mercadológicos contribuíram para um avanço incrível no poder de processamento das GPUs e na demanda de tarefas para as quais as GPUs foram projetadas.

> Até onde eu consigo entender, a GPU nada mais é que um processador adicional dedicado a renderização gráfica.

Não. As GPUs foram concebidas pensando-se em gráficos, pois o custo de processamento das intricadas funções matemáticas associadas a perspectiva e interpolação de texturas eram muito exigentes para os processadores. Com o tempo, essas operações foram tornando-se simples em relação ao poder computacional dos CPUs, mas a quantidade destas cresceu muito (especialmente relacionado com a resolução crescente dos jogos), então as GPUs foram aproximando-se de grandes matrizes de processamento paralelo (é comum em um jogo ter de se aplicar a mesma operação nos milhões de pixels da tela centenas de vezes por segundo), e esse processamento massivo e paralelo começou a chamar a atenção para outras tarefas, e alguns hacks começaram a ser utilizados para simular problemas de física (por exemplo) como pixels de textura, e as companhias perceberam isso e abraçaram o processamento genérico (com a introdução de shaders programáveis como grande marco), e hoje a GPU na verdade é um monte de núcleos que *pode* ser usado para gráficos.

> Como a GPU pode auxiliar nos processamentos?

A GPU conta com centenas de núcleos (A GTX 960 tem 1024 núcleos de processamento) - muito além de qualquer PC doméstico. Esses núcleos são altamente especializados para operações incondicionais e seriais, ou seja, processar dados sem desvios de execução, principalmente quando atuando sobre largas regiões de memória (quando o paralelismo dos núcleos pode ser melhor explorado), que é o cenário comum ao manipular grande volume de informações de mídia.

> Este *offloading* normalmente ocorre através de bibliotecas como a openMP. Em que exatamente estas bibliotecas auxiliam?

Embora as GPUs tenham grande poder computacional, ainda são periféricos controlados pelo CPU. Estas bibliotecas fornecem rotinas de comunicação para enviar comandos e dados para os periféricos computacionais (entre eles, a GPU). Elas ligam o programa com os drivers para expor as funções necessárias ao processamento genérico assim como as bibliotecas gráficas expõe as funcionalidades do OpenGL, por exemplo.

> Existe algum *overhead* de transferir estes processamentos para a GPU? Compensa pagar este  *overhead* para processar na GPU?

Sim e sim (em programas bem projetados). Toda comunicação entre periféricos é considerada overhead, inclusive a comunicação entre núcleos do mesmo CPU possui overhead. Os dados precisam ser formatados em tipo e protocolo e seguir para transferência. Avanços recentes nas tecnologias de barramento e memória RAM permitiram diminuir a latência  associada, possibilitando experiência de tempo real, e também permitiram aumento da quantidade de dados transmitidos, fazendo com que o overhead de preparação seja compensado pelo acréscimo de resultado percebido (os termos técnicos associados com demora de preparação e quantidade de resultado por tempo são *latency* e *throughput*).

---

Um exemplo ilustrativo (com bastante liberdade):

Digamos que você tem uma array de 1024 números, e deseja realizar uma série de operações sobre eles, como somar uma constante.

Com um CPU de 8 núcleos, cada núcleo fica responsável por processar 128 números, já na GPU com seus 1024 núcleos, cada núcleo fica responsável por apenas um número. Assumindo que a GPU atue na metade da frequência e cada operação demore 1 clock, é uma vantagem de 64 vezes na velocidade de processamento.

Os dados tem de ser transmitidos para a GPU, então talvez a velocidade não compense em uma operação tão simples, mas digamos que você deseja somar um número, multiplicar, comparar com outra array, tirar o cosseno... uma série de comandos. Assim que os dados estiverem na GPU, a CPU só precisa enviar os comandos necessários (como no caso dos *shaders* usados em jogos), e está livre para outras tarefas que a GPU não é especializada em fazer, como verificar entradas do usuário, comunicar com outros periféricos, tratar de outros programas (etc) e depois requisitar o resultado.